# Can't get correct alpha values from individual BufferedImage pixels

Tags: java, image, swing, alpha

I need to get RGBA values, modify RGB, then set RGB (and A) values again.

However, it seems to return `255` for all the pixels, even though I know the image I'm loading has transparent pixels in it.

Here's an SSCCE

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestImage {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/affy/Pictures/salamenceavatar.png"));

            BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(
                    image.getWidth(),
                    image.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
            );

            Graphics2D g = buff.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

            for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                    Color c = new Color(buff.getRGB(x, y));
                    int alpha = c.getAlpha();
                    System.out.println(alpha);
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to let us know what error message, exception, or incorrect behavior you're seeing.  "I can't" usually isn't enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Color(int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20boolean)) instead, passing it `true` to tell it you want to extract the alpha value from the supplied packed `int`

```
Color c = new Color(buff.getRGB(x, y), true);
```

From the JavaDocs...

> Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value
>   consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in
>   bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component
>   in bits 0-7. If the hasalpha argument is false, alpha is defaulted to
>   255. 
> **Parameters:**
>  rgba - the combined RGBA components 
> hasalpha - true if the alpha bits are valid; false
>   otherwise

Comment: I believe I tried that, I guess I messed it up, it works now. Thanks!